# Task и использование коллекций в C#

Tags: c#, коллекции, task

Допустим, у меня есть `List<Task>` и при создании новой задачи, я кладу в эту коллекцию, что будет с коллекцией если эта задача выполнит свою работу? Удалится ли она из коллекции сама?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С коллекцией ничего не будет. Task - это такой же класс, как и любой другой. Task никак не управляет коллекциями, в которых находится.